# What does a cloud application look like?

Tags: hadoop, salesforce, cloud, distributed-computing

There are many applications that are called Cloud applications. As an example, those companies who deliver a web-based application for lots of customers (e.g. [Salesforce](http://www.salesforce.com/)) over the web call their application a Cloud App. On the other hand, many people know Cloud-based Apps as the ones built on top of Hadoop or similar technologies that could scale-up to many computing resources.

Now the Q is, is there an exact definition of a Cloud App? Is there any good resources on Cloud Apps? There is a [nice link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430340.aspx), but it is a little bit old.

Comment: http://www.dilbert.com/strips/comic/2012-10-21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no clear definition.

The loosest is simply any application that does most of the work on a server, not on the local client's device.

The strictest definition I've heard is an application that runs almost entirely on a cluster of virtualized servers that are provided as a service, not hosted on-site. And the client device does almost nothing; probably just a simple web browser with minimal scripting.

Any definition in between could make sense in context.

I wouldn't get too caught-up by it. "Cloud" is mostly just a marketing buzz-word with no serious technical definition.